# DriverManager won't seem to connect DB

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a school assignment for a client/server application and can't seem to connect using the JDBC DriverManager. I have set up the driver for the schema I am using, it351, and seem to have everything in order but it never fires through the connection to tell me it's connected. Any words of wisdom from the crowd? I do show the driver in the services task pane and I have saved my password so I don't have to share it with the class. Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
   private JButton custButton;
   private JButton prodButton;
   private JButton exitButton;
   private JPanel p1;
   private JPanel p2;
   private JPanel p3;
   private JTextArea data;
  // private String message = ""; // message from server
   private String localhost; // host server for this application

public GUI()
   {
      super( "Database Data Retrieval" );
      setSize(825, 800);
      setVisible(true);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setResizable(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Container c = new Container();
      add(c);
      c.setLayout(new BoxLayout(c, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      // create and add jpanels for components
      p1 = new JPanel(); //(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
      c.add(p1);
      p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
      c.add(p2);
      p3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
      c.add(p3);

      data = new JTextArea(35, 70);
      JScrollPane dataScroll = new JScrollPane(data);
      dataScroll.setPreferredSize(null);
      p1.add(data);
      p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 10));
      data.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      data.setVisible(true);

      // create buttons
      p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( null, "Database Controls"));
      custButton = new JButton( "Retrieve Customer Data");
      p2.add (custButton);
      p2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(50,0)));
      prodButton = new JButton( "Retrieve Product Data" );
      p2.add(prodButton);
      p2.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      p2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
      exitButton = new JButton ("    Exit    ");
      p3.add(exitButton);
      p3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 0, 20, 0));

// register events for buttons
ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
      custButton.addActionListener( handler );
      prodButton.addActionListener( handler );
      exitButton.addActionListener( handler );
}


   private void displayMessage( final String messageToDisplay )
   {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable()
         {
            public void run() // updates displayArea
            {
               data.append( messageToDisplay );
            } // end method run
         }  // end anonymous inner class
      ); // end call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater
   } // end method displayMessage

   private void connect()
   {
       Connection conn = null;
       try
                {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/it351?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", ""); //Connect
                    displayMessage("******* Connection created successfully *******"); //informs user of connection 
            }           
             catch (Exception err)
                {
                }
   }

   private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
   {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
      {         
         if (event.getSource() == custButton)         
         {   
             displayMessage( "******* Attempting connection *******\n" );
             connect();           
         }


         if (event.getSource() == prodButton)
         {                 

         }



         if (event.getSource() == exitButton)
         {
             System.exit(0);
         }

    }// end of actionperformed
}// end of buttonhandler 

}// end of GUI class
```

Comment: Maybe print your exception to actually see what goes wrong...

Comment: I don't get an exception. it just stops after displaying "Attempting connection" and nothing else happens. No errors, nothing...

Comment: How do you know that there is no exception if you catch it but ignore it? If nothing is printed after "Attempting connection" you definitely got an exception.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver I guess it's telling me it can't find the driver but everything I read about it confuses the heck out of me on it.

Comment: You have to add the driver to your classpath.

Comment: How do I do that? that is one thing no one ever went over in class.

Comment: How are you executing your program? Is it an excutable jar file? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Sorry, it's in netbeans IDE.

Comment: Download the latest mysql jdbc connector and consult google on how to add a library in netbeans.

Comment: Actually if u re using netbeans it has the driver in it but if you are using eclipse you have to download it

Comment: Under drivers in Netbeans in the services tab it show MySQL(Connector/J driver). Isn't that it? I have it set up and can click connect with that but can't get it to work from the code. I clicked on properties and am loading exactly what it say in the driver line and the URL line.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add the connector in the library under run, set project configuration, customize, library, add library and then select the driver.